# Serialize using DataContract Serializer

Tags: c#, xml, windows-phone-8, serialization, datacontractserializer

I have **List of IProductDescription** that i want to serialize in a valid xml using a DataContract Serializer. Such that i can deserialize it later. Here is `ProductDescription` class that implements `IProductDescription` interface.

```cs
[DataContract]
[KnownType(typeof(ProductDescription))]
public class ProductDescription : IProductDescription
{
    [DataMember]
    public List<AssetDescription> Assets { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string ProductId { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    [DataMember]  
    public string FormattedPrice { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public DateTime? ExpirationDate { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public ProductStatus ProductStatus { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string ProductPageUrl { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string PackageDownloadLocationUrl { get; set; }

}
```

Here is my AssetDescription Class

```
[DataContract]
public class AssetDescription
{
    [DataMember]
    public string Type { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string IconUrl { get; set; }

}
```

Now i wanted serialize it. I already have an implementation of serialization. After reading here and there i got to know that i have to add some knowntype attribute but i am not getting successful. so can somebody help me in this problem.

**Edit** :- after adding attribute things are getting serialized but in wrong way like it top part of my serialized string.

```
<ArrayOfanyType xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays">
  <anyType xmlns:d2p1="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/ProductDescriptionModel" i:type="d2p1:ProductDescription">
    <d2p1:Assets>
```

But when I deserilize it then it is throwing an exception that ArrayType should not be **ArrayOfanyType**

**I want to serialize/desrialize the List of IProductDescription**

Comment: What about ProductStatus, is that an Object or Enum?

Comment: What have you tried? What isn't working about it? You'd only need a `KnownType` attribute here if you were trying to serialze/deserialize `ProductDescription` as an `IProductDescription`.

Comment: @PatrickMagee i have made an edit can you take a look now ? I want to serialize/desrialize the List<IProductDescription>

Comment: If you're trying to serialize `List<IProductDescription>` then `IProductDescription` will need `DataContract` and `DataMember` attributes, as well as a `KnownType` attribute for `ProductDescription`.

Any `DataMember` *not* in `IProductDescription` that are in `ProductDescription` will not participate when serialized/deserialzed as `IProductDescription`.

Comment: @PrestonGuillot can you made me more clear what should i done. i really did not get it.

Comment: @loop Check my answer, I tested it and it works.

Answer (score 3):

Try putting the KnownType in the serialiser.

```cs
void Main()
{
    var serializer = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(IProductDescription),  knownTypes: new[] { typeof(ProductDescription) });

    using(var writer = new XmlTextWriter("C:\\Temp\\test.xml", Encoding.UTF8))
    {
        serializer.WriteObject(writer, new ProductDescription());   
    }

    using(var reader = new XmlTextReader("C:\\Temp\\test.xml"))
    {
        var o = serializer.ReadObject(reader) as IProductDescription;

        Console.WriteLine(o.ToString());
    }
}

public enum ProductStatus { One, Two, Three }

public interface IProductDescription
{
    [DataMember]
    List<AssetDescription> Assets { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    string ProductId { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    string Description { get; set; }

    [DataMember]  
    string FormattedPrice { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    DateTime? ExpirationDate { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    ProductStatus ProductStatus { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    string ProductPageUrl { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    string PackageDownloadLocationUrl { get; set; }

}

[DataContract]
public class ProductDescription : IProductDescription
{
    [DataMember]
    public List<AssetDescription> Assets { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string ProductId { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    [DataMember]  
    public string FormattedPrice { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public DateTime? ExpirationDate { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public ProductStatus ProductStatus { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string ProductPageUrl { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string PackageDownloadLocationUrl { get; set; }

}

[DataContract]
public class AssetDescription
{
    [DataMember]
    public string Type { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string IconUrl { get; set; }

}
```

Comment: Attribute 'KnownTypeAttribute' is not valid on this declaration type. It is only valid on 'class, struct' declarations.

Comment: It'd also be good form to include `DataContract` on the enumeration, and attribute its members with `EnumMember`, as an aside.

Comment: You're right, I deleted my comment - good to know. I've never run into this when using WCF since dealing with interfaces as request/response members there isn't going to be common. For WCF, it turns out you can use `ServiceKnownType` on an interface to achieve the desired result, but that wouldn't work here since the serializer is being invoked directly.